# How to shift/offset iloc sum?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello am trying to do the equivalent of excel function `sum(offset)`, offsetting the "years" to sum. So I have ten columns years `1` to year `10`. But if `maturity_years` is `2` I just want to sum the 2 columns. so the first row would add just first 2 columns `100 + 100`. then 2nd row `maturity_years = 4` so sum only `ECL_y1` to _`ECL_yr4`  i.e. `244 +244 +244 +244..` etc.

so far i have

```
df_base_ifrs['ECL_LT']=df.iloc[:,1:10].shift(df['maturity_years']).sum(axis=1)
```

but not working

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'maturity_years': [2, 4, 0, 8],
               'ECL_y1': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y2': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y3': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y4': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y5': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y6': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y7': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y8': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y9': [100, 244, 443, 124],
               'ECL_y10': [100, 244, 443, 124],})
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of the dataframe? Will be much easier to understand your question.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`? if so, please mention this in your question. and what is maturity years?

Answer (score 0):

Hey just to update everybody I finally figured it out. Albeit kicks out warning

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

However, If you can improve on time efficiency please put your answer forward

```
for i in range(0, len(df_base)):
    row = df_base.iloc[[i]]  
    mat_date = row['MATURITY_YEARS_D'].values[0]
    result = row.iloc[:,68:68+mat_date].sum(axis=1)
    result_as_float = result.values[0]
    row['ECL_LT'] = result_as_float
    print(result_as_float)
```